# Where are the GCC values for macros such as __DBL_EPSILON__ defined?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, floating-point, compiler-construction

I'm using GCC and MinGW as compilers. I wanted to find the actual values from some of the floating-point constants but they're all defined as compiler macros. Eg: `__DBL_EPSILON__`, `__DBL_MAX__`, `__DBL_MIN__`, etc. I can't find them anywhere. I even grep trough the entire GCC source code along with all his libs and couldn't find any of these compiler macros.
On MSVC they're all defined into float.h header like that:

```cpp
#define DBL_DECIMAL_DIG  17                      // # of decimal digits of rounding precision
#define DBL_DIG          15                      // # of decimal digits of precision
#define DBL_EPSILON      2.2204460492503131e-016 // smallest such that 1.0+DBL_EPSILON != 1.0
#define DBL_HAS_SUBNORM  1                       // type does support subnormal numbers
#define DBL_MANT_DIG     53                      // # of bits in mantissa
#define DBL_MAX          1.7976931348623158e+308 // max value
```

It is apparently not the case for GCC. How does it work and where are these values ?

Comment: Perhaps in the compiler and not a .h file.  Why does it make a difference for your application _where_ they come from?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica as mentioned, I already grep-ed in the entire GCC source code and couldn't find any values attributed to these compiler macros.

Comment: Did you grep for `EPSILON` or `DBL_EPSILON`? The compiler may be looking for the underscores separately from the rest of the identifier. Btw, if all you want is the values, use printf, e.g. `printf("%.50e\n", __DBL_EPSILON__);`

Comment: @user3386109 Yes I did actually. That's how things are defined : ```#define DBL_EPSILON __DBL_EPSILON__```.

Comment: @Alexandru Why is finding this source important ?

Answer (score 2):

Gcc defines a number of macros when it starts, unless you specify the `-undef` command-line option. The definitions are created directly in memory and then given to the preprocessor. You can see the code in the gcc source at [gcc/c-family/c-cppbuiltin.cc](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/c-family/c-cppbuiltin.cc;h=4672ae8486a74b832bb865f03f721eeb112417b9;hb=HEAD), in the function [builtin_define_float_constants](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/c-family/c-cppbuiltin.cc;h=4672ae8486a74b832bb865f03f721eeb112417b9;hb=HEAD#l118)
but I doubt that's what you're looking for. (If you look at that code, you'll see that the macros are created using `sprintf` using formats like `"%s_EPSILON"`, which is why you didn't find them with grep.)

If you want to see the builtin macros and their values, you can use a command like:

```
gcc -E -dM -x c /dev/null
```

Some command-line options change the list, starting with the various target options and `-std`, so use the options you're interested in. You can also change `-x c` if you're interested in another language in the C family, such as c++.

You probably want to pipe the output through `sort`, since it doesn't come out in any logical order. (I guess it's the dump of a hash table.)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for ! Thank you !